# How to prepare this particular data for heatmapping with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, heatmap

I have this issue that I will start describing by showing the result.

I have exported some tables from R to Excel to generate heatmaps. I did this because I could manually add some 0's that I did not manage to get with R. Here is one heatmap that I did to understand:

[image]

Now I would like to try to code it fully with R. Here is how I proceeded until now.

```
#subsetting my df by decade
sub1 = subset(df, decade == "1950-1959")
sub2 = subset(df, decade == "1960-1969")
sub3 = subset(df, decade == "1970-1979")
sub4 = subset(df, decade == "1980-1989")
sub5 = subset(df, decade == "1990-1999")
sub6 = subset(df, decade == "2000-2009")
sub7 = subset(df, decade == "2010-2019")
sub8 = subset(df, decade == "2020-2029")

#then for every sub[1:8] I repeated this code, to obtain the weighted values shown in the heatmap.
sub1_pond = sub1 %>% 
  group_by(decade, julian_day, lat_grouped) %>% 
  count() 

colnames(sub1_pond) = c("decade", "julian_day", "lat_grouped", "nb_obs_perday_perdecade_perlatgroup")

ponderate = sub1_pond %>% 
  group_by(decade, lat_grouped) %>%
      summarize(sum_nb_tot = sum(nb_obs_perday_perdecade_perlatgroup))

sub1_pond = sub1_pond %>%
  ungroup %>%
  left_join(., 
            ponderate) %>% 
  mutate(newval = nb_obs_perday_perdecade_perlatgroup/sum_nb_tot)

sub1_pond_range <- sub1_pond %>%
  mutate(ranges = cut(julian_day,
                      seq(15, 155, 7))) %>% 
  group_by(ranges, lat_grouped) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(sums = sum(newval)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  arrange(., lat_grouped)
```

Here is the resultant table for 1 subset:

```
> sub1_pond_range 
      ranges lat_grouped       sums
1    (15,22]           1 0.03571429
2    (22,29]           1 0.01785714
3    (29,36]           1 0.07142857
4    (36,43]           1 0.08928571
5    (43,50]           1 0.16071429
6    (50,57]           1 0.03571429
7    (57,64]           1 0.07142857
8    (64,71]           1 0.08928571
9    (71,78]           1 0.05357143
10   (78,85]           1 0.05357143
11   (85,92]           1 0.10714286
12   (92,99]           1 0.14285714
13  (99,106]           1 0.05357143
14 (106,113]           1 0.01785714
15   (64,71]           2 0.05555556
16   (78,85]           2 0.05555556
17   (85,92]           2 0.16666667
18   (92,99]           2 0.33333333
19  (99,106]           2 0.33333333
20 (106,113]           2 0.05555556
```

Here is the data for sub1 which is small in comparison with sub[2:8]:

```
> dput(sub1)
structure(list(lat = c("59", "59", "55", "59", "59", "63", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "63", "59", "59", "59", "57", "56", "56", "59", 
"63", "63", "59", "63", "57", "59", "57", "63", "63", "63", "63", 
"63", "63", "63", "63", "63", "63", "55", "55", "55", "59", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "58", "59", "63", "59", "56", "59", "57", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"59", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "63", "59", "59", "59", "61", 
"59"), long = c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), date = c("1951-03-22", 
"1951-04-08", "1952-02-03", "1952-03-08", "1953-02-22", "1953-03-12", 
"1954-01-16", "1954-02-06", "1954-03-14", "1954-03-28", "1954-04-02", 
"1955-01-23", "1955-03-06", "1955-03-13", "1955-04-08", "1955-04-11", 
"1955-04-12", "1956-03-25", "1956-04-01", "1956-04-02", "1956-04-03", 
"1956-04-22", "1957-02-19", "1957-02-19", "1957-03-03", "1957-04-03", 
"1957-04-04", "1957-04-05", "1957-04-08", "1957-04-09", "1957-04-14", 
"1957-04-14", "1957-04-14", "1957-04-14", "1957-04-14", "1958-02-08", 
"1958-02-08", "1958-02-08", "1958-02-16", "1958-02-17", "1958-02-19", 
"1958-03-05", "1958-03-05", "1958-03-15", "1958-03-30", "1958-03-30", 
"1958-03-30", "1958-04-02", "1958-04-04", "1958-04-06", "1958-04-06", 
"1958-04-09", "1958-04-09", "1958-04-20", "1959-01-18", "1959-02-01", 
"1959-02-01", "1959-02-01", "1959-02-08", "1959-02-15", "1959-02-15", 
"1959-02-15", "1959-02-19", "1959-02-22", "1959-03-02", "1959-03-07", 
"1959-03-08", "1959-03-08", "1959-03-22", "1959-03-22", "1959-03-30", 
"1959-03-30", "1959-04-10", "1959-04-14"), julian_day = c(81, 
98, 34, 68, 53, 71, 16, 37, 73, 87, 92, 23, 65, 72, 98, 101, 
102, 85, 92, 93, 94, 113, 50, 50, 62, 93, 94, 95, 98, 99, 104, 
104, 104, 104, 104, 39, 39, 39, 47, 48, 50, 64, 64, 74, 89, 89, 
89, 92, 94, 96, 96, 99, 99, 110, 18, 32, 32, 32, 39, 46, 46, 
46, 50, 53, 61, 66, 67, 67, 81, 81, 89, 89, 100, 104), year = c(1951L, 
1951L, 1952L, 1952L, 1953L, 1953L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 
1954L, 1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 1956L, 1956L, 
1956L, 1956L, 1956L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 
1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1957L, 1958L, 1958L, 
1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 
1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1958L, 1959L, 
1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 
1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 1959L, 
1959L), decade = c("1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959"
), time = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
    lat_grouped = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
    "1", "1", "1", "2", "1"), year_centered = structure(c(-36, 
    -36, -35, -35, -34, -34, -33, -33, -33, -33, -33, -32, -32, 
    -32, -32, -32, -32, -31, -31, -31, -31, -31, -30, -30, -30, 
    -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -29, -29, 
    -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, 
    -29, -29, -29, -29, -29, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, 
    -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, -28, 
    -28), class = "AsIs")), row.names = 24:97, class = "data.frame")
```

My question is: how to prepare my data (as I am not able to assign 0's) to make a heatmap fully on R without having to manually use Excel?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you "unable to assign `0`'s"?  Is this perhaps an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure whay you are trying to do, but I *think* you are trying to get a cross-tabulation of decimal values by two discrete columns but are having difficulty filling in the values where there is no data with zero values. The base function `xtabs` will do that in one line. I took you sub1_pond data example and applied `xtabs` using the discrete variables that you used in your Excel "heatmaps". Notice that you do get zeros. If you have missing julian_dates then you may need to augment the data. I think there are tidyverse function that will "complete" such cases but I'm not a user so I would use `seq` and `merge` to do that if needed.

```
xtabs(newval~julian_day+lat_grouped, data=sub1_pond)
          lat_grouped
julian_day          1          2
       16  0.01785714 0.00000000
       18  0.01785714 0.00000000
       23  0.01785714 0.00000000
       32  0.05357143 0.00000000
       34  0.01785714 0.00000000
       37  0.01785714 0.00000000
       39  0.07142857 0.00000000
       46  0.05357143 0.00000000
       47  0.01785714 0.00000000
       48  0.01785714 0.00000000
       50  0.07142857 0.00000000
       53  0.03571429 0.00000000
       61  0.01785714 0.00000000
       62  0.01785714 0.00000000
       64  0.03571429 0.00000000
       65  0.01785714 0.00000000
       66  0.01785714 0.00000000
       67  0.03571429 0.00000000
       68  0.01785714 0.00000000
       71  0.00000000 0.05555556
       72  0.01785714 0.00000000
       73  0.01785714 0.00000000
       74  0.01785714 0.00000000
       81  0.03571429 0.05555556
       85  0.01785714 0.00000000
       87  0.01785714 0.00000000
       89  0.07142857 0.05555556
       92  0.01785714 0.11111111
       93  0.00000000 0.11111111
       94  0.03571429 0.05555556
       95  0.00000000 0.05555556
       96  0.03571429 0.00000000
       98  0.03571429 0.05555556
       99  0.03571429 0.05555556
       100 0.00000000 0.05555556
       101 0.01785714 0.00000000
       102 0.01785714 0.00000000
       104 0.01785714 0.27777778
       110 0.01785714 0.00000000
       113 0.00000000 0.05555556
```

Here's how to fill in the zero entries. I'm doing this on a smaller data object:

```
dat <- data.frame( a = sample(1:20, 8), b=sample(1:15, 8), z=runif(8))
 dat2 <- tidyr::complete(dat, a, b, fill=list(z=0))
 dat2
# A tibble: 64 × 3
       a     b     z
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     2     1 0    
 2     2     3 0    
 3     2     4 0    
 4     2     7 0    
 5     2     8 0    
 6     2     9 0.584
 7     2    12 0    
 8     2    15 0    
 9     9     1 0    
10     9     3 0.925
# … with 54 more rows
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I did not know this function, I will take a look at it. To say it in an other way, I manage to get a data table (`sub1_pond_range`) only when there is something to calculate. That is why some ranges of julian days (7 days period) are missing (e.g. all the 3rd lat_group in this example), but I would like to get them in the `sub1_pond_range` with a 0 assigned, like it appears in the heatmap. Hope it is clearer now :)